# Is it Possible Create multiple instance of FormData() in sinle JavaScript File

Tags: javascript

I have two File upload controls(multiple file uploads) in single page .
i need to create two objects for FormData() like

dataone= new FormData();//this is for one fileupload controls to
datatwo= new FormData(); this is for another fileupload controls

can any one help to how to do it

Comment: Can you post, what you have tried and did you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function and send the form id in the arguments and return a new form data:

```
function frmData(frm){
    return new FormData(frm);
}
```

Now this can be used like:

```
var frm1 = document.querySelector("#frm1"),
       frm2 = document.querySelector("#frm2"),
       frmdata1 = frmData(frm1),
       frmdata2 = frmData(frm2);
```